# Terminal create flush right output

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to create a script that outputs something at the end. Now how can I create an output that's centered or flush right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For right justification, you can simply print the text with a field width equal to the column width of the terminal:

```
printf '%*s\n' $COLUMNS 'some text'
```

For center justification, you need to do some math to account for the length of the text you want to print - see for example [Ubuntu 16.04 : Center greeting command in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/818207/178692)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *center* often you may define a function (for example in `.bashrc`):

```
center() { printf '%*s\n' $[COLUMNS/2 + ${#1}/2] $1 ;}
```

and then

```
$ center 'some text'
```