# Centering a string in another

Tags: bash

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I have a string of length `N` which I want to center in another string.

Thus setting some string of length N

```
old_string="***"
```

I want a new string (length 55) with the old string centered in it.

```
new_string="     ***     "
```

How can I do this in bash ?

Although in actual fact the trailing spaces are redundant, so I can-simply have

```
new_string="     ***"
```

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You could do essentially the same as this, but with a fixed value 55 in place of the `COLUMNS` variable: [Ubuntu 16.04 : Center greeting command in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/818207/178692)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the bash shell, try this:

```
short='---' 
long='abcdefgh'
half=$(( ${#long} / 2 ))
result=${long:0:${half}}${short}${long:${half}}
printf "%s\n" $short $long $half $result
```

Result:

```
---
abcdefgh
4
abcd---efgh
```

Reference:

```
man bash
/ Parameter Expansion
```